# Spotfire, Barchart width, and setting display intervals on x-axis

Tags: bar-chart, spotfire

[image]

If I click the x-axis, year, and go to custom expression, it says [Year] for the upper picture. Also, for the upper picture case, I cannot adjust the bar width.

But for some reason if I type <[Year]>, into the expression, it gives me this, and suddenly I can change the bar width to what I want it to be in Properties.
[image]

I don't understand what is causing this difference.

I want to make my bar chart to be thicker like the bottom one, but I also want my x-axis to display years on 5-year interval like, 1995 - 2000 - 2005 - 2010... but I don't know how I can do it.

Please take into consideration that I don't have any basis with codes for custom expression. So if you were to answer to my question with codes for custom expression, please give me a full code that works.

I am experiencing a really big limitation with me not being able to manipulate custom expressions, but currently I don't have time to start learning it from the basics... I've tried to look it up, but lots of them were talking about binned columns, and I just don't understand.

[image]

## scsimon

I cannot press ok. I am not sure if I am doing this right tho. Just to be clear, what I want is from the first screenshot, everything stays the same, but just by bar getting thicker. I so still want separate bars for each year, I just want the x-axis label to label on 5 year interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binning is used on the back end a lot of times naively and can be tricky to use in a custom expression. The bin function you want to use is `BinBySpecificLimits()` The first think to do is create a calculated column for your year if you haven't already.

`Year([DateColumn]) as [Year]`

Then use your Bin function.

```
BinBySpecificLimits([Year],1994,2000,2005,2010,2015,2020)
```

This is evaluated as bins where the bin is

```
Bin <= 1994
1994 < Bin <= 2000 
2000 < Bin <= 2005
etc...
```

I can understand your urgency... but I would also strongly suggest you play with the custom expressions. They are very `SQL` like. Things only get harder :)

Comment: How do I create a calculated column? Do I do it in a Data table, or directly in my chart?

Comment: I copy and pasted your BinBySpecificLimits([Year],1994,2000,2005,2010,2015,2020), into my bar chart's custom expression, and it doesn't allow me to manipulate the bar width.

Comment: Data table.. `Insert > Calculated Column`

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding here... What I wanted was my bar chart displaying a bar for every year, but just on my y-axis the labels are on 5 year interval. Also, if I type in Year([DateColumn]) as [Year] in the custom expression in Insert > Calculated Column, I can't press Ok button for some reason.

Comment: Well what's the name of your column containing your dates? What error does it give you on the right of your expression box?

Comment: i edited the question, and added a screenshot. plz take a look at it

Comment: You already have a calculated column for your Year it seems, so you don't need the first line. If you didn't already have this column, you would have to do this in two separate steps. You can't add two columns at once.

Comment: Ok... so what's the problem now @EricKim or were you going to close the question?